# Q: Proving G is d-colorable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I'm studying graph theory, coloring at the moment. I'm stuck with a proof of the following exercise:

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a connected graph and let $v \in V$ be such that $deg(v)\lt d$. If $deg(w)\le d$ for all $w \in V-{v}$, then $G$ is $d$-colorable.

I have an idea that I could use Brooks' Theorem but I'm not really sure. I'd appreciate it if someone could give me a hand here

Comment: By "$gr$", do you mean the degree of a vertex?

Comment: oh yes! We write it like this

Comment: That's entirely fine. Just asking for clarification.

Comment: Okay, if you have an idea of how to do it, tell me. Thank you. :)

Comment: I have some idea, but just to be safe, what does "related" in "related graph" mean?

Comment: means that for any pair of vertices u and v in G, there is at least one path from u to v.

Answer (score 4):

We can do this by induction on the number of vertices, for a fixed $d\geq1$.

Clearly this is true for a graph with a single vertex.

For the induction step, assume the statement is true for all connected graphs with $n-1$ or fewer vertices ($n\geq 1$), all with degree at most $d$ and at least one vertex with degree strictly less than $d$. Take any connected graph $G=(V,E)$ with $|V|=n$, maximum degree $d$ and at least one vertex $v$ with degree strictly less than $d$.

If we remove $v$ and any edges going to $v$ from $G$, we will be left with a graph $G'$ with $n-1$ vertices, maximal degree $d$, and because $v$ had at least one neighbor, there is at least one vertex in $G'$ with degree strictly less than $d$ (namely, $v$'s previous neighbors).

Note that $G'$ might not be connected, but we may use the induction hypothesis on each connected component, to show that it can be coloured using at most $d$ colours.

Now add $v$ back in. It has less than $d$ neighbors, so at least one colour is available to use on $v$. This finishes the proof.

---

If you want to use Brooks's theorem instead, note that the degree requirement neatly takes care of the cycle graph and complete graph exceptions in that theorem:

- If $G$ is a cycle graph, then the requirement that there is at least one vertex with degree strictly less than $d$ means $d\geq3$, and cycle graphs are always 3-colorable
- If $G$ is a complete graph, then the requirement that there is at least one vertex with degree strictly less than $d$ means there are at most $d$ vertices, so you can give each vertex its own colour

For any other graph, Brooks's theorem says exactly that since the maximal degree is (at most) $d$, the graph is $d$-colourable.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I think I'll take the induction demonstration

Comment: @VOLTUUH I just realized, the induction part is missing a detail: Removing $v$ might make $G'$ not connected / not related. So you need to use the induction hypothesis on each connected component of $G'$, rather than on all of $G'$. However, each component has at least one neighbor to $v$, so the degree assumption still holds. This also means the induction assumption must hold for all graphs with $n-1$ _or fewer_ vertices. But the main structure of the proof still remains.

Comment: But to say that I need to use the induction hypothesis on every connected component of G′, rather than on everything G′, is not the same thing? @arthur

Comment: @VOLTUUH No, it is not the same. The induction hypothesis requires connectedness, because that's what we have said the induction hypothesis is, because that's what we ultimately want to prove. Thus we can't use it on all of $G'$.

Comment: So I need to use the connection on all the components of G' ? Okay, I think I got it. I'm gonna change that. Thank you!

Comment: Just to be safe, can I change the inductive case to "For the induction step, assume the statement is true for all connected component of graphs with $n−1$ or fewer vertices $(n≥1)$ " or should I clarify something else?

Comment: @VOLTUUH No, each connected component is a connected graph in itself. So you don't need to specify "the connected components of graphs". Just "for all connected graphs with $n-1$ or fewer vertices" is fine.